# How to show point values in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table `active deposit`. I am showing its values in a view called `$total_dep`. It shows value when there is a complete number `e.g 10 or 100`. But it does not show decimal values `e.g 0.001`. how I can show decimal values like 0.001.

number_format(). working for this

```
<div class="num" data-start="0" data-end="{{ number_format($member->amount,3) }}" data-postfix="{{ $basic->symbol }}" data-duration="1500" data-delay="0">{{number_format( $member->amount,3) }}</div>
```

not working for this type

```
<div class="num" data-start="0" data-end="{{number_format( $total_deposit,3) }}" data-postfix="{{ $basic->symbol }}" data-duration="1500" data-delay="0">0</div>
```

this should work

```
<div class="num" data-start="0" data-end="{{ $total_deposit,3 }}" data-postfix="" data-duration="1500" data-delay="0">{{ number_format($total_deposit,3) }}</div>
```

controller code

```
public function getDashboard()
    {
        $data['general'] = GeneralSetting::first();
        $data['site_title'] = $data['general']->title;
        $data['basic'] = BasicSetting::first();
        $data['page_title'] = "User Dashboard";
        $data['member'] = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
        $mem = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
        $data['last_deposit'] = Deposit::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id','DESC')->take(8)->get();
        $data['total_reference_user'] = User::whereUnder_reference($mem->reference)->count();
        $data['total_deposit'] = Deposit::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->sum('amount');

        /*$data['total_deposit1'] = Deposit::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->sum('amount');
        $data['total_deposit2'] = ManualFund::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->sum('amount');*/
        $data['total_deposit_time'] = Deposit::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->count();
        $data['total_deposit_pending'] = Repeat::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->whereStatus(0)->count();
        $data['total_deposit_complete'] = Repeat::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->whereStatus(1)->count();
        $data['total_rebeat'] = RebeatLog::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->sum('balance');
        $data['total_reference'] = Reference::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->sum('balance');
        $data['total_withdraw_time'] = Withdraw::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->count();
        $data['total_withdraw_pending'] = Withdraw::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->whereStatus(0)->count();
        $data['total_withdraw_complete'] = Withdraw::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->whereStatus(1)->count();
        $data['total_withdraw_refund'] = Withdraw::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->whereStatus(2)->count();
        $data['total_withdraw'] = Withdraw::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->whereStatus(1)->sum('amount');
        $data['total_fund'] = Fund::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->sum('total');
        $data['total_dep'] = Deposit::where('user_id', auth()->id())->latest('id')->whereStatus(0)->sum('amount');

       return view('user.dashboard',$data);
```

Comment: You can use floatval($total_deposit) function in your php file.

Answer (score 1):

use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) -

```
{{ number_format($total_deposit,3) }}
```

Or keep it as-

```
{{ $total_deposit }}
```

And change your view to-

```
<div class="num" data-start="0" data-end="{{ $total_deposit,3 }}" data-postfix="" data-duration="1500" data-delay="0">{{ number_format($total_deposit,3) }}</div>
```

Comment: options.maxDepth) { toggle(a); } } else if ('sf-dump-ref' == elt.className && (a = elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.substr(1); elt.className += ' '+a; if (/[\[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a != elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { s = a.nextSibling; elt.appendChild(a);

Comment: my web page is now like this

Comment: please see my updated answer, and you should try `dd($total_deposit)` on controller

Comment: $data['total_deposit'] = Deposit::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->sum('amount');

Comment: where to add "DD" in this line

Comment: after this line do this `dd($data['total_deposit'])`

Comment: $data['total_deposit'] = Deposit::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->sum('amount');
        dd($data['total_deposit']);

Comment: now its showing only 0.001 my web page  has been removed?

Comment: but what about my web page :)

Comment: @WaqarAli please see my updated answer, add it to your view and remove dd from controller

Comment: it is working for $member->amount . but not for $total_deposit type

Comment: that's why you should have added your controller code in your question and full view

Comment: please check question

Comment: please add your controller

Comment: @Sole0415  controller added

Comment: try `dd($data)` in controller before `return view('user.dashboard',$data); ` and show us

Comment: array:20 [▼
  "general" => GeneralSetting {#434 ▶}
  "site_title" => "Bitcash"
  "basic" => BasicSetting {#435 ▶}
  "page_title" => "User Dashboard"
  "member" => User {#430 ▶}
  "last_deposit" => Collection {#438 ▶}
  "total_reference_user" => 0
  "total_deposit" => "0.001"
  "total_deposit_time" => 1
  "total_deposit_pending" => 1
  "total_deposit_complete" => 0
  "total_rebeat" => 0
hetting this

Comment: mean along with your view.

Comment: please can you add answer according to my code. please

Comment: I have edited your question with this should work message, add that line on your view

Answer (score 0):

From your controller, you can return using number_format(). See below example,

```
public function getPrice() {
    return ($float) $this->price;
}
```

Comment: $data['total_deposit'] = Deposit::whereUser_id(Auth::user()->id)->sum('amount');

Comment: in your scenario, use $total_deposit = ($float) $data['total_deposit']; and call this variable in your view page.